Using Leibniz Integral Rule to Evaluate a log-sine Integral
I am looking for someone to check my work here.
$$I(a)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(1+a\sin^2(x))dx$$
Using Leibniz/Feynman's trick, I differentiate both sides with respect to $a$, leaving me with
$$I'(a)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{1+a\sin^2(x)}\ dx$$
$$I'(a)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{a+\csc^2(x)}\ dx$$
$$\text{now let }u=\cot(x)$$
$$I'(a)=-\int_{\infty}^0\frac{1}{a+1+u^2} \left( \frac{1}{u^2+1}\right) \ du = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{a+1+u^2} \left( \frac{1}{u^2+1}\right) \ du$$
$$I'(a)=\frac{1}{a}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{u^2+1}-\frac{1}{a+1+u^2}\ dx$$
$$I'(a)=\frac{1}{a}\left( \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}}\right) \right) = \frac{\pi}{2a}\left( 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}}\right)$$
$$I(a)=\frac{\pi}{2}\int\frac{1}{a}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}} \right)da$$
$$u=\sqrt{a+1}$$
$$I(a)=\frac{\pi}{2}\int\frac{1}{u^2-1}\left( 1-\frac{1}{u}\right) 2u\ du=\pi\int\frac{1}{(u-1)(u+1)}(u-1)\ du =\pi\int\frac{1}{1+u}\ du$$
$$I(a)=\pi\ln(1+\sqrt{a+1})+C$$
$$I(0)=0\Rightarrow C=-\pi\ln2$$
after simplifying the final result I found was:
$$I(a)=\pi\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{a+1}}{2}\right)$$

Before substitution, should $I(a)=\frac{\pi}{2}\int\frac{1}{a}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}} \right)da$ be $I(a)=\frac{\pi}{2}\int\frac{1}{a}\left(1- \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}} \right)da$?
